# I have a WSDL webservice I am trying to access from java/Blackberry

Tags: web-services, blackberry, sdk, wsdl, axis

I have a WSDL webservice I am trying to post and receive information from via java within a Blackberry app. I have used axis1.4 to build the stub and other class files within Eclipse. I have have the BB interface already designed. I can run a simulator and navigate to the page to enter the information (in this case Account Registration). I just need to know how to make set up the transfer. I currently have button on the screen as well that shows "Congratualtions" message when clicked but that should be on an "if" I need to make the button call the webservice, post information entered in fields to database, and get back a reply ( in this case true/false). My app is built on giving and receiving info to about 7 different methods within my webservice. Sending normally between 2 and 5 fields of data and receiving 1-3. Seems like I have all the pieces of the puzzle I just can't link them. I have read post on many other sites and this one about implementing wsdl but the examples are too simple to be useful to me. Please help.   Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into [ksoap2](http://ksoap2.sourceforge.net/) ? I think what you need to know is how to pass complex objects [Complex Objects & Ksoap2](http://seesharpgears.blogspot.com/2010/10/ksoap-android-web-service-tutorial-with.html)